# Parent not include children if parrent is miss in another year in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

i have data,

```
parentid    geo     CustomerId  Sales   Year
171     A   171     10  2014
171     A   172     20  2015
171     A   172     30  2014
171     A   173     40  2014
```

query,

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales] }
 ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([DIMCustomer].[ParentGeoCode].[ParentGeolCode].ALLMEMBERS ) }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME

  ON ROWS FROM
  ( SELECT ( { [DIMCustomer].[ParentSkId].[Level 02].allmembers } )

  ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [DIMCustomer].[HierarchyCategory].&[Hierarchy] } )
  ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Year].[Year].&[2015], [Year].[Year].&[2014] } )
  ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube])))

  WHERE ( [Year].[Year].CurrentMember, [DIMCustomer].[HierarchyCategory].&[Hierarchy],
  [DIMCustomer].[ParentSkId].[Level 02].allmembers)
```

output-  coming from this query is 10 but as per requirment i need 100 if i select year 2014 and 2015

Answer (score 0):

Try taking `[Year].[Year].CurrentMember` out of your `WHERE` clause and replacing with the All member of that hierarchy `[Year].[Year].[All]`

By the way:
  1. You do not need to nest sub-selects but it is more readable if you use other axes.
  2. No need to include any `.allMemeber` functions like this in a sub-select `[DIMCustomer].[ParentSkId].[Level 02].allmembers`

This is the simplified script:

```
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales] } ON 0, 
 NON EMPTY { ([DIMCustomer].[ParentGeoCode].[ParentGeolCode].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON 1
FROM
  ( 
   SELECT   
       { [DIMCustomer].[HierarchyCategory].&[Hierarchy] }   ON 0, 
       { [Year].[Year].&[2015], [Year].[Year].&[2014] }     ON 1 
   FROM [Cube] 
  )
 WHERE 
   (
     [Year].[Year].[All],
     [DIMCustomer].[HierarchyCategory].&[Hierarchy],
     [DIMCustomer].[ParentSkId].[Level 02].allmembers
   );
```